# how to get values from select option box using for loop [select option box is created dynamically]

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I'm trying to get values from select option box. but i get the first option box value only.

i want all option box values which is selected.suppose in code there is 10 select option box is created, when user clicks on button then i want all that 10 select option box values and get stored in a variables or display that options which is selected by the user.

i have done some code please refer my work from comment section it is on the jsfiddle website. for more better understanding you can refer that. sorry for my rookie language, i'm new to stackoverflow. please don't hesitate to edit my information i would like that.

Comment: CODE http://jsfiddle.net/34q5aeoc/. please refer this.

Comment: You have only one button. Which is to generate the options right? Which button is used to store the values of the check boxes?

Comment: i want values from the option box. like e.g first option box user select TYPE A, then in second option box user select TYPE C and so on i want that specific option values like TYPE A,B and C.

Comment: @BlackPearl you can use another button for that

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/34q5aeoc/2/ Updated code

Comment: You are assigning the same id to all the elements. Check the code snippet in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on the following jsfiddle link:
[jsfiddle.net/ypb9zLe8/][1]

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/ypb9zLe8/
```

Removed some code and inserted one extra button. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The id for all the elements are same in your code. Use `document.querySelectorAll`
to get the list of elements.

```js
function getdata() {
  var num = document.getElementById("number").value;
  console.log(num);

  $(document).ready(function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      $('<div><select id="select-meal-type' + i + '"><option value="TYPE A">TYPE A</option><option value="TYPE B">TYPE B</option><option value="TYPE C">TYPE C</option></select><br></div>').appendTo('#container');
    }
  });
}

function getValues() {
  var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=select-meal-type]")
  var values = Array.from(nodeList).map(val => val.value)
  console.log(values);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br> type a number<input type="text" id="number">
<br><br>
<div id="container"></div>
<button onclick="getdata()">GET DATA</button>
<button onclick="getValues()">GET VALUES</button>
```